# Python Multiprocessing Not Speeding Up

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, pathos

I have a code where a shared resource is changed by a function call. So far, for each input vector (the input matrix of dimension rxc), I'm running it serially.

I want to change a shared resource (say R) with each function call. I've so far tried using Python Multiprocessing and Pathos Multiprocessing to speed this up. I even tried np.apply_along_axis to try and speed it up.

So far what I've noticed was that the serial processing is the fastest way. I'm lost as to why this is happening.

I've tried the following approaches

1. np.apply_along_axis : Only slight delay (constant time shift)
2. Pathos.multiprocessing.ProcessingPool.Map : up to 10x delay
3. multiprocessing.Process (manual split): up to 5x delay
4. multiprocessing.Pool : in line with Pathos results.

I am new to python parallel programming and may be doing something wrong. What is a good way to do it?

**Update : Self Organizing Map code attached**

I'm quoting what I'm doing.

```
class SOM(object):

    def __init__(self, X):
        pool = Pool()
        pool.ncpus=4
        self.map = pool.map


    def train_single( self, x, lr, r):
        b = np.argmin(np.linalg.norm(self.W-x, axis=1))

        N = np.where(np.linalg.norm(self.Y-self.Y[b],axis=1)<r)[0]
        d = np.linalg.norm(self.Y[N]-self.Y[b],axis=1)
        H = np.array([np.exp(-d**2/np.max(d)**2*0.5)]).T

        H/=H.max()
        gradients =  - (self.W[N] - x) * H * lr
        if np.isnan(gradients).any():
            return
    #
        self.W[N] += gradients

    def train_batch_parallel(self, X):
        self.W = np.random.random(size=(100, X.shape[1]))
        self.Y = np.array([[i, j] for i in range(10) for j in range(10)])
        self.X = X

        r = 10
        lr = .5
        self.rs = np.repeat(r, X.shape[0]).astype(float)
        self.lrs = np.repeat(lr, X.shape[0])
        for k in range(1, 100):
            self.rs *=0.8# np.append(self.rs, np.repeat(r * 0.8 ** k, X.shape[0]), axis=0)
            self.lrs *=0.9# np.append(self.rs, np.repeat(lr * 0.9 ** k, X.shape[0]), axis=0)
            #parallel execution using the pool.map
            self.map(self.train_single, X, self.lrs, self.rs)
```

Comment: Odds are your computation is cheap relative to the cost of serializing the units of work for transmission to worker processes and back. If you're not using shared memory, that means copying all the data to the worker, and the results back. I can't be more specific because you haven't provided a [MCVE].

Comment: I'd wager that the context switching in the OS is doing is taking more time than it is to do the computations in serial. Hence why you would see serialized performance being better.

Comment: It's hardly to believe that multiprocessing.Pool gives you up to 10x delay, maybe you do it wrong ? Show some code, so we could help you

Comment: I've updated the question with the code. Please take a look.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Thank you. That helped me. Turns out that I was passing huge object variables to the worker. Just turned it into a global variable inside the worker function. Thanks a ton